# File state lost after git stash command

Tags: git, git-stash

```
echo Hello. > a.txt
git add .
echo Bye. >> a.txt
git status -s
>>> AM
```

We can see state is `AM`,
But on doing the following

```
git stash
git stash pop
git status -s
>>> A
```

State is `A`.
Why is the `M` state lost?

Comment: Would `git stash apply` or `git stash apply --index` (instead of `git stash pop`) work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the expected behavior. To reconstruct it as you expect (save A & M) use

```
git stash pop --index
```

From documentation:

```
git-stash(1):

If the --index option is used, then tries to reinstate not only the working
tree’s hanges, but also the index’s ones. However, this can fail, when you have
conflicts (which are stored in the index, where you therefore can no longer apply
the changes as they were originally).
```